# How to use Jquery or other simple action to hide or show a form-group on view Create. ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I hide or show, one

```html
<div class="form-group"> </div>
```

on View Create?
Follow the code:

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.vigencia, "Vigência", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="vigencia" name="vigencia">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Sim</option>
            <option value="0">Não</option>
        </select>            
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vigencia)
    </div>
</div>
//$("#blocovigencia").show();
//$("#blocovigencia").hide();
<div class="form-group" id="blocovigencia">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data_inicio, "Data Início", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.data_inicio, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Data Início", type = "date"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.data_inicio)
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data_limite, "Data Limite", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.data_limite, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Data Limite", type = "date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.data_limite)
    </div>
</div>
```

My mission is: If value of Vigencia is 1 show data. if is 0 hide data.

Sorry if I'm not direct. I dont know english very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write `jQuery` function to do that.  The below code should do the work.  It adds a `jQuery` event during page load and `.change` event fires whenever you change selection in the drop down.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#vigencia").change(function () {
    var test = this.value;
    if(test == '1')
            $(".form-group").show();
    else
            $(".form-group").hide();
    }); 
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xzgod5g/) example.